# Count number of clients that have subscriptions

Tags: java, comparative-review

I have two working solutions, one using an accessor (`getSubscription()`) and one using a member variable (`subscription`).

Which one should I use?  Which solution is correct?

### Solution 1:

```
List<Client> myClient = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
public class Client {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    protected String cID;
    protected boolean subscription = false;
}
```

```
public int getNumberOfSubsrtipion(){
    int count = 0;

    for( Client myCustomer: myClient ){
        if( myCustomer.subscription ){
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

### Solution 2:

```
List<Client> myClient = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
public class Client {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    protected String cID;
    private boolean subscription = false;

    protected boolean getSubscription(){
        return this.subscription;
    }
}
```

```
public int getNumberOfSubsrtipion(){
    int count = 0;

    for( Client myCustomer: myClient ){
        if( myCustomer.getSubscription() ){
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

The solutions differ only in the content of the `if` conditional in the function.

Comment: `I have two working solutions,` so why would only 1 be correct ? what do YOU think is the difference here ? where/when would it have an impact ? would it even make a difference ?

Comment: First of all boolean primitive will be init as false by default. Second: If the method `getNumberOfSubsrtipion` is inside a class, then it is better to access the field; it is more encapsulating. But remeber if there will be inheritence, the classes in hierarchy will use their own fields, only getter will allow overriding.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/10722110/9248765

Comment: Another design consideration: Once you make your fields `protected`, you no longer control them in the case of subclassing (I can just extend and toy with the `protected` fields, no reflection needed). By using the method, you're stating you want what the _method_ does, which should be consistent across all classes involved in inheritance (if people play nice with LSP).

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8466790/217324

Comment: Oracle recommends that you use `Getters` and `Setters`. They list an exception as a case of your class acting as a `struct`. In my opinion, if your class acts as a `struct`, you should create a `struct` and not a `class`. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-programmingpractices.html. I recommend reading every page.

Answer (score 6):

The name `subscription` suggests to me that the field contains detailed information about a subscription to some service. A subscription is not inherently a true-false concept. In this case `subscribed` (or alternatively `subscriber`) would be better. And since booleans in Java conventions have a special accessor prefix "is" it would become:

```
public boolean isSubscribed() {
    return subscribed;
}
```

The common convention in Java is that properties are accessed through accessors and property visibility should always be as restrictive as possible. Thus the correct choice would be the latter.

Getter methods normally access an existing value with minimal processing. A method that counts subscriptions should not be "disguised" as a getter. A better name would be `countSubscriptions()` or `countSubscribers()`. A parable can be found from the `java.util.Collection` class which provides an `isEmpty()` method and a `size()` although the former might be reduced to `size() == 0`. The difference is that in some cases `size()` might have to count all values while `isEmpty()` only needs to check if the first one exists.

Never use the "my" prefix in variable names. It is a sign that the programmer has not spent the necessary time to figure out a proper name. Whenever you think about using the "my" prefix you need to immediately step back and figure out a better name. The word "my" does not communicate anything about the purpose of the field (it's not mine, after all). Do not use them even in throwaway code as it is can create a bad habit.

You have named the list of Clients as a singular form `myClient`. Usually lists are named in plural form, such as `clients`. Then later you assign the value of a Client into a variable named `myCustomer`, which seems odd.

Taking into account the notes above, the end result would be:

```
public class Client {
    ....
    private boolean subscribed = false;

    public boolean isSubscribed() {
        return subscribed;
    }
}
```

...and...

```
List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();

public int countSubscriptions() {
    int count = 0;
    for (Client client: clients) {
        if (myCustomer.isSubscribed()) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

With streams the method body would be fair bit shorter:

```
    return clients.stream()
        .filter(Client::isSubscribed)
        .count();
```

Comment: Extra points for using `is...` property and of course keeping with the getter. Especially if there is a link to an actual "subscription" instance(s) later. Because if the class links to actual subscriptions then the boolean does not have to be a field at all; you could just use `return subscriptions.size() > 0` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine. Just in first case scenario you could use the getter if needed by some other feature.

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to be a private class or a "throw away" class that isn't visible to the user, then it isn't really important which one you use.  If you are going to publish the class, the I would use `getters` and `setters` so you can hide the implementation details of how the fields are stored.  This also allows you to change the way they are stored without impacting the user's application.

Another consideration is the nature of the field.  If it is a mutable object, then a getter allows you the opportunity to return a deep copy so the actual object can't be altered by the user.

Comment: There are no throw away classes in production code. Every class is worthy regardless of whether they are exposed in the API or not. This kind of thinking leads to unmaintainable spaghetti code.